# Is it possible to have site wide default settings for all jQuery validation uses on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to have site wide default settings for all jQuery validation uses on my site, I want every form to use the below settings, but then on a per form basis change the rules and messages. Is this possible?

```
 $('#myForm').validate({

  errorClass: 'field-validation-error',
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.next('span').remove();
        error.insertAfter( element )
         .removeClass('field-validation-error')
         .addClass('ui-state-error');

    },
    success: function(label) {
            label.remove();
  }          
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put those codes within-

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
       //your site wide codes
});
```

And save it into a site wide js file, e.g. `global.js`

Comment: NICE! I was just clicking around S.O. and stumbled across this question/answer. I was about to modify the plugin defaults directly last night for the specific needs of my site. Thanks for saving me the pointless effort!

Answer (score 2):

**I found it**

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
   errorClass: 'field-validation-error',
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.next('span').remove();
        error.insertAfter( element )
         .removeClass('field-validation-error')
         .addClass('ui-state-error');

    },
    success: function(label) {
                label.remove();
    }
});
```